# robot_localization: Differential parameters and covariance

Tags: imu, navigation, ekf, odometry, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to fuse visual odometry with an IMU sensor to get pose estimates.

Neither of these give covariance by default, so I am setting them myself.

My question is: Is at least one absolute position required for the covariance to converge? Is this expected behaviour or is something wrong?

For whatever values I try, unless I use the visual odometry with differential=False, the covariance increases forever. I have tried having very small covariance diagonals in the messages, slightly bigger in the noise, and large (but not huge) for the initial estimate.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271630/robot_localization:-differential-parameters-and-covariance/) by [cwalt](https://answers.ros.org/users/32038/cwalt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2017-09-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want the pose covariance to be constrained (i.e., to *not* grow without bound), yes, you need at least one absolute pose reference. Differential mode is currently handled by differentiating the pose and treating it as a velocity. I have a branch of r_l in the Locus Robotics fork that computes relative pose differently, but it assumes that the message covariance can be used directly.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2018-01-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cwalt](https://answers.ros.org/users/32038/cwalt/) on 2018-01-03**:
Thanks for the answer! It now seems reasonably intuitive. I have ended up using GPS with high covariance as the absolute source.